# Animated images on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, animation

[image]

I want these images above to pop up when someone hovers over them, each image pops up and comes to the center when someone hovers a mouse over the image, also they should  be arranged in that format. I want to do this in WordPress, I am designing a website and the client wants that effect. Is it possible friends? please someone assist me.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<nav>
    <img src="http://winn-brown.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Logo-new.png" id="logo">
</nav>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent" onclick="">
        <div class="child bg-one">
            <a href="#">Los Angeles</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent right" onclick="">
        <div class="child bg-two">
            <a href="#">London</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent" onclick="">
        <div class="child bg-three">
            <a href="#">New York</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent right" onclick="">
        <div class="child bg-four">
            <a href="#">Hollywood</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent" onclick="">
        <div class="child bg-five">
            <a href="#">Dubai</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent right" onclick="">
        <div class="child bg-six">
            <a href="#">San Francisco</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
/* Global Styling */
html, body {margin:0px; padding: 0px;}

nav {
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 80px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 999;
}

#logo {height: 80px; margin-left: 20px;}

.wrapper {
    padding: 50px 50px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 80px;
}

.right {float: right !important;}
/* Image zoom on hover + Overlay colour */
.parent {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.child {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

/* Several different images */
.bg-one {background-image: url(https://media.timeout.com/images/101602611/image.jpg);}
.bg-two {background-image: url(http://s1.it.atcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/2-London.jpg);}
.bg-three {background-image: url(https://media.timeout.com/images/101484105/image.jpg);}
.bg-four {background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Hollywood_Sign.jpg/1280px-Hollywood_Sign.jpg);}
.bg-five {background-image: url(http://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/tnl_redesign_article_landing_page/public/1453920892/DUBAI-554088081-ABOVE0116.jpg?itok=dcoZnCrc);}
.bg-six {background-image: url(http://blog.whitepages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/san-franc.jpg);}


a {
    display: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*text-decoration: none;*/
}

.parent:hover .child, .parent:focus .child {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.parent:hover .child:before, .parent:focus .child:before {
    display: block;
}

.parent:hover a, .parent:focus a {
    display: block;
}

.child:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(52,73,94,0.75);
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .parent {width: 100%; margin: 20px 0px}
        .wrapper {padding: 20px 20px;}
}




.hello {display: none}
```

You will try this using that code when you hover the image then it will be zoom out the image. I think it will help you.